# Java - recursively find all files with an extension with a modified date between two dates

Tags: java, file

I am able to find all the files I would like that end with an extension recursively with an extension such as .zip.

But I would love to filter that further between two dates based off modify date.

I've searched around and have found ways to do it just for .zip or just for the dates. I have been able to do both but not recursively down the directories and subdirectories

As you can see below I created a `FileFilterDateIntervalUtils` (which I have added later on) which I want to do the filtering of .zip (or others, to be configured) and a time range as an `accept`. I would like to add that to the walk somehow but I am new to this.

```
public void finder(String dirName) {
    System.out.println("Using directory: " + dirName);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
    FileFilterDateIntervalUtils filter_date = new FileFilterDateIntervalUtils("2019-08-17 00:00:00 AM",
            "2019-08-22 12:00:00 PM");

    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(dirName))) {
        paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


public FileFilterDateIntervalUtils(String dateStart, String dateEnd) {
    this.dateStart = dateStart;
    this.dateEnd = dateEnd;
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
}

public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    Date d = new Date(new File(dir, name).lastModified());
    String current = sdf.format(d);
    if(!name.endsWith(".zip")) {
        return false;
    }
    return ((dateStart.compareTo(current) < 0 && (dateEnd.compareTo(current) >= 0)));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Sounds like you have some code already. Maybe if you post it someone can suggest an improvement.

Comment: I have added some code, I was fighting with the formatter.

Comment: So change the code of FileFilterDateIntervalUtils so that it not only checks that the file modification date is between the two dates, but also that its named ends with .zip. It's just a matter of combining two conditions with  `&&`.

Comment: @JBNizet I have been trying to do that, I have added that code now, but I am not sure how to add that filter to the 'walk' stream.

Comment: To filter a Stream<Path>, you need a Predicate<Path>, i.e. a function that takes a Path as argument and returns true or false. Refactor your `accept` method to take a Path as argument instead of a File and a String.

Comment: So I will need to take the path and then loop through the path for all the files in that path to see if they meet the criteria?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a built-in mechanism in Java for "walking" the file tree, called [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html#filevisitor). It does all the walking and recursive traversal - you only need to provide the logic for what to do when each file is visited.

As an added bonus, it has an implicit performance optimization in a sense that it doesn't load all the paths into memory, but "walks" files/directories one by one, useful for directories with many files/directories inside.

Here's a working example:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class Example {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // walks the file tree starting from current directory '.', using an 
    // instance of anonymous class that implements FileVisitor interface
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("."), new FileVisitor<Path>() {

      @Override
      public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path,
                                       BasicFileAttributes attrs) {

        // some starting date
        Date start = new Date();
        // some ending date
        Date end = new Date();

        if (path.endsWith(".zip") && 
            (attrs.creationTime().toMillis() >= start.getTime() && 
             attrs.creationTime().toMillis() <= end.getTime())) {

          // if you use Java 8 or later, you can work with Instant, like this
          // attrs.creationTime().toInstant().isAfter(start.toInstant())

          System.out.println(path);

          // or optionally convert to File and do something with it
          File file = path.toFile();
        }

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }

      @Override
      public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file,
                                             IOException exc) {
        // unused
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }

      @Override
      public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                                                IOException exc) {
        // unused
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }

      @Override
      public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                                               BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        // unused
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Agreed I have seen a lot of literature on this but I cannot find the correct implementation.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on but  the following line gives me two errors:

Files.walkFileTree(Path.of("."), new FileVisitor<>() {


'<>' cannot be used with anonymous classes Example.java 
The method of(String) is undefined for the type Path

Comment: Probably the IDE is complaining about the "Diamond Operator", i.e. "<>". Try setting language level to Java 7 (or higher) or try the updated code from above.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Apache's `IOUtils` class is for. Rework your code so that it calls [`IOUtils.listFiles()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)). This method lists files in a directory. Make use of Apache's [`IOFileFilter`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter.html) so that it filters out files based on the `lastModified()` date criteria that you desire. This should get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform what I would like to do in my question above. I still want to test the answer provided by Danilo Radenovic. I do need to add parameters for dates.... not difficult. I also need to clean up: FileFilterDateIntervalUtils.java

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dirName = "";
    String extension = "";
    Finder find = new Finder();
    System.out.println("Args Length: " + args.length);
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("You need to include two arguments, the root directory and the extension to search");
    } else {
        dirName = args[0];
        extension = args[1];
    }
    System.out.println("Using starting directory " + dirName);
    System.out.println("Using extension " + extension);
    find.finder_walkFileTree(dirName, extension);
}
```

}

```
public class Finder {


public void finder_walkFileTree(String dirName, String extension) {
    try {
        Path p1 = Paths.get(dirName);
        System.out.println("Path: " + p1.toString());
        FileFilterDateIntervalUtils filter_date = new FileFilterDateIntervalUtils("2019-08-17 00:00:00 AM",
                "2019-08-22 12:00:00 PM");
        Files.walkFileTree(p1, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                String fileString = file.toAbsolutePath().toString();
                if (filter_date.accept(dirName, fileString, extension)) {
                    System.out.println("file found at path: " + file.toAbsolutePath());
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class FileFilterDateIntervalUtils implements FilenameFilter {
String dateStart;
String dateEnd;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;

public FileFilterDateIntervalUtils(String dateStart, String dateEnd) {
    this.dateStart = dateStart;
    this.dateEnd = dateEnd;
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
}

public boolean accept(String dir, String name, String extension) {


    Date d = new Date(new File(name).lastModified());
    String current = sdf.format(d);
    if (!name.endsWith(extension)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("found zip " + name);
        System.out.println("Current date: " + current);
        System.out.println("Start date: " + dateStart);
        System.out.println("End date: " + dateEnd);
        if((dateStart.compareTo(current) < 0 && (dateEnd.compareTo(current) >= 0))) {
            System.out.println("We are within the date range!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public Predicate<? super Path> accept(Stream<Path> paths) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}